# Dreamweaver: Syntax Error, Unexpected '?' when using null-coalescing operator

Tags: dreamweaver, php-7.2

My server is running PHP 7.2.26.
I'm coding in Dreamweaver CC (Ver 19.2.1).
I'm using null-coalescing operator on a page, but Dreamweaver is giving me "Syntax Error, Unexpected '?'" as a line error.

My code:

`($_SESSION['form_data']['smtpEmailAddress'] ?? "")`

It works fine when viewing in a browser. I only get the error in Dreamweaver.
Is there a way to get Dreamweaver to accept Null-coalescing Operator?
Dreamweaver is currently set to use PHP 7.1.  7.2 is not an option within preferences.

I know I could just ignore the Dreamweaver error, but I do scan my code for errors using the Dreamweaver error indicators.  I'd rather fix Dreamweaver than just ignore the error.

Comment: Null coalesce is php7.0 so apparantly dreamweaver isn't even correctly handling php7.1

Comment: Besides, Dreamweaver, what are some other apps that people are using to code PHP?

Comment: I have used Netbeans and PhpStorm extensively. They're both fantastic products. Netbeans is free. PhpStorm is probably better than Netbeans but its not free. They both run on all the popular OSs.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to fix it in Dreamweaver 2020:

1. Go to Edit>Preferences>PHP>Select your 7.x version of PHP
2. Go to Site>Manage Sites>(select your site)>Advanced settings>PHP>Select your 7.x version of PHP.

And sorted, the errors are gone.

This is an issue with the lack of explanation in the options, not a bug. When you select PHP in the global preferences it establishes that version as default for the creation of NEW SITES, but if you are importing sites from previous versions it keeps the old configuration. It is explained in detail here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/dreamweaver/using/setting-coding-environment.html

> **Dreamweaver supports PHP versions 5.6 and 7.1.**
>
> You can choose to compile your site’s PHP files with PHP version 5.6 or 7.1 using the Site Setup dialog box (on a per-site basis), or application preferences (for all PHP files saved outside Dreamweaver sites). Dreamweaver then sets up the code hints, and linting checks for the selected PHP language version.
>
> For new sites in Dreamweaver, the default PHP compiler is set to the version specified in Edit > Preferences > PHP.